# Subtracting two times in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, time, simpledateformat

I get a start time using this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            String start_time = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

And I get an end time using this code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
            String end_time = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
```

I want to get the time elapsed, so something like `start_time - endtime = elapsed_time` would be nice, but it doesn't seem to be possible. I'm still not great at understanding objects, but I guess since Strings are objects, I can't easily get the elapsed time. What would be an easy way to do this, but to have `elapsed_time` as a String?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your best choice is probably Joda Time: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/
It has an Interval class and a Duration class, both can be used to measure time differences. The Interval has a ReadableDuration, which in turn has a toString method to format it.

From the Joda Time documentation:

```
// interval from start to end
DateTime start = new DateTime(2004, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2005, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Interval interval = new Interval(start, end);
```

Comment: although true it should be a comment, unless you show how to do it with joda-time ...

Comment: Added some clarification, does this address your concerns @NimChimpsky?

Comment: Bit weird to use a separate library for this, because date subtraction is supported in Android/Java by default.

Comment: not that weird, joda time is great always the first thing I add to a project

Answer (score 2):

if you suppose to have:

- calBegin = calendar set to start time
- calEnd = calendar set to end time

then you can use something like:

```
long elapsedMs = calEnd.getTime().getTime() - calBegin.getTime().getTime();
```

Where elapsedMs = milliseconds elapsed between begin and end

Answer (score 2):

```
 Date elapsed= new Date(sdf.parse(end_time).getTime() - sdf.parse(start_time).getTime());
        System.out.println(sdf.format(elapsed));
```

1. Convert your start and time time to long type.
2. do the subtraction.
3. convert the obtained result to java.util.Date object
4. format using the SimpledateFormat to get the result in a specific format

Answer (score 2):

With `string` this is not possible. You should be using the `Date` object:

If `cal` is `Calendar`:

```
Date start_date = cal.getTime();
//change to calendar to other date
Date end_date = cal.getTime();
long total_time = end_date.getTime() - start_date.getTime();
```

If `cal` is something else like a custom object returning a `String`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
Date start_date = sdf.parse(cal.getTime(), 0);
Date end_date = sdf.parse(cal.getTime(), 0);

long total_time = end_date.getTime() - start_date.getTime();
```

total_time is total time in miliseconds

Comment: What imports are needed? date or sql? I'm guessing date, but just making sure.

Comment: I'm trying this, but I get a red line under parse.

Comment: There is an other parameter needed, see http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String, java.text.ParsePosition)